# Android: Add themes to existing project

Tags: java, android, themes

I have a really old app that I am updating and want to use modern theming methods, probably Material Design 3.

If I create a new Android project, it creates some special folder to res/values folder, which has two files - one for light and one for dark.

[image: modern theme folder]

I am unable to figure out how to add this special folder to my existing project as it looks like this at the moment.

[image: old values folder]

I couldn't find a tutorial online, and when I try to add a folder and call it themes, it doesn't have the same icon.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: When you want to add a new Resource file there is a Available qualifier that is called Night Mode, select it with the ">>" button and select Night inside the Night mode.

Comment: @Eguti I don't get that option. Is there something I need to do first, or is there a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: OK, I tried again, this time right clicking on the 'res' folder. It created a values-night folder. Still doesn't show it combined in the special folder view that you get on a new project, but at least I was able to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself. I compared, and made similar, files in the root project directory between the files in my project and a new Android project.

[image: Files I edited]

I had also edited `.idea\name` file.

Then I just did Build->Clean Project, and closed and re-opened the project in Android Studio, and the issue was fixed with the smart folder organisations automatically done by the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

While I was updating an old app to use the new theming methods, I did the following using the command line:

1. Navigate to the `res/values/` directory for my app, and add a new file named `themes.xml`.
2. Navigate back one directory, to the `res/` directory and add a new directory called `values-night`.
3. Navigate into the newly created `res/values-night` directory and add a new file called `themes.xml`.

Now when I went back into Android Studio, it had automatically created the special `themes/` directory within the `res/values/` directory, which contains the two files - one for the light theme, and one for the dark theme.

You also need to update the following line in your manifest file to point to your theme files, rather than the `style.xml` file.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, change this line from this:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

To this:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.YourAppName">
```

**Theme.YouAppName** is the name that you add to the `themes.xml` files, as the style name, e.g:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.YourAppName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```